# MapKit how to opt-out from clustering when an annotation is selected

Tags: mapkit, ios11, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkclusterannotation

I’m using iOS 11 clustering and it works really fine, basically you just need to ad an identifier to the `clusteringIdentifier` property of an `MKAnnotationView`. 
Everything works perfectly but I have an issue, when a user select a marker from a map I'd like to avoid clustering at least on the selected maker.
The mapView doesn't seems to have a property to disable clustering. The only plausible solution is to `nil` `clusteringIdentifier`, but even if I do that it keeps to cluster.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {  
         view.clusteringIdentifier = nil  
    }
```

Can someone post me in the right direction?

Comment: There is no such thing as `view.clusterIdentificator`.

Comment: I correct the question it was a typo

Answer (score 2):

Give the `clusteringIdentifier` a *unique* value. If the `clusteringIdentifier` has a value that is not shared with any other annotation views, it won't cluster with any other annotation views.

You can obtain a unique value by saying `UUID().uuidString`.

Comment: UUID().uuidString for swift 4.2 and beyond

Comment: @JBarros35 Thanks, I'll just change it directly

Comment: @matjan thanks, it's odd how much difficulty I seem to have getting this right. :)

Comment: I have this question too.  How do I set the clusteringIdentifier of the members on the did select to get them to vacate the cluster?  Thanks!